# Is there a type which can switch between Float and Double?

Tags: c++

Is there any predefined type which can switch between float and double in some specific condition.

For example, some type, I would like this type be float; sometimes I need this type becomes double.

Comment: get used to `typedef` or just use a cast

Comment: Nothing predefined. Use casts or create your own type.

Comment: You may want to expand on the purpose behind this a little bit: When would you like the switch to happen, at compile time or at runtime? What is the desired benefit? Are you trying to save memory space? Perhaps you need to match a signature of an external function? In any case, these explanations would improve your question a lot.

Comment: Give more context. You could use templates to avoid code repetition if you want identical functionality for different types. If you want to just convert between the two, use cast.

Comment: Without more information we cannot provide specific help. OTOH I think you could use C++11 template aliases to select between both types using certain conditions: `template<bool condition> using floatdouble = typename std::conditional<condition,float,double>::type;`

Comment: Converting a `float` to a `double` is called a _promotion_ and guaranteed to give the exact same result every time. When casting from a `double` to a `float` you may encounter loss of precision, use a _static cast_ ex. `float fValue = static_cast<float>(dValue)` when casting from a `double` to a `float`.

Answer (score 0):

Use always double, it is recommended everywhere, if you don't have huge arrays in your program. This is a thing that I learned in programming competitions and because of which I failed many times previously because of precision problems.

Comment: Not only that, it can also be very easily converted to float, should it be necessary to do so.

Comment: That however automatically doubles the needed memory (and probably also the processing time, although modern CPUs have special big registers that limit the impact I think, but still the data needs to be transferred there first). As a general advise your answer might work, but be careful if you need a lot of floating-point variables in performance critical areas.

Comment: There are indeed few cases where one really needs `double` for precision, often the use of `double` points to a problem with properly understanding floating point math. Using `double` by default is not a good advice since it not only consumes twice as much memory but also delays the detection of the previously mentioned problem (but does not solve it).

Comment: @thecoder When you need to handle data of 100GB or more, and struggle with disk i/o and system crashing due to limited memory after hours of processing, then you'll reconsider. Different types are there for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want to do. As @thecoder suggested the simplest option is to just use double. To convert it to float you just assign it:

```
double d = 0.1;
float f = d;
```

However, if you need to write code that must work both for float and double, use a template:

```
template<NumberT>
NumberT sum(NumberT first, NumberT second) {
  return first + second;
}
```